# How do I make the wrong answer count as wrong answer?

Tags: c, windows

In running, it displays whether the answer is wrong or right, but even when it is wrong it is still get added into the Number of Correct Answers. What do I do or add to make it work?

````
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char choice;
    int correctAnswer = 0, wrongAnswer = 0;

    printf("Who developed C?\n");
    printf("A. Dennis Leary \tC. Dennis Rodman\nB. Dennis Ritchie \tD. Dennis Ruth");
    printf("\nAnswer: ");
    scanf("%c", &choice);

    switch (choice)
    {
    case 'A':
        printf("Wrong Answer.\n");
        break;
    case 'B':
        printf("Correct Answer.\n");
        break;
    case 'C':
        printf("Wrong Answer.\n");
        break;
    case 'D':
        printf("Wrong Answer.\n");
        break;
    default:
        printf("Invalid Answer\n");
        
    }
    if ('B')
        correctAnswer++;
    else
        wrongAnswer++;
    
    printf("Number of Correct Answers: %d\n", correctAnswer++);
    printf("Number of Wrong Answers: %d\n", wrongAnswer++);
}```


I expect the code to add the wrong answers to be added in the Number of Wrong Answers and it seems it recognized all answers as a correct answer.
````

Comment: The `if ('B')` test will always be true; you need `if (choice == 'B')`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your own words, where the code says `if ('B')`, exactly what do you expect this to mean? (In particular: are you expecting it to have something to do with the `choice` variable? If so, **why**? How should the program know that?)

Comment: Tip, add a space `scanf(" %c", &choice);`.  This will save time for the next assignment.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this

```
if ('B')
```

is always true. Change it to:

```
 if (choice == 'B')
```